# speed of importing data from another solr is very slow

Tags: performance, solr

I was using SolrEntityProcessor to import data from another solr. It was working but the speed is only 30 documents/s which is weigh below I was importing from SQL Sever (7000 documents/s).

I am wondering if I was missing something and if there is any way to improve the speed.

A litte information about my solr cloud. I have 3 shards on three different servers and all of them are within same domain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [SolrEntityProcessor gets slower and slower](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201307.mbox/%3CCABGq8w_70ijwaJBG93Z2chcC7oq9WTM2DkQRhwz6ZiggHS-vDQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

> SolrEntityProcessor is fine for small amounts of data but not useful for such a large index. The problem is that deep paging in search results is expensive. As the "start" value for a query increases so does the cost of the query. You are much better off just re-indexing the data.

To resolve this:

> The common way to deal with this issue is by filtering on a value that
>   would return fewer results every query, as a creation_date field, and every
>   query change this field range. For your data import use-case you might want
>   to generate your data-import.xml with different entities, each one for
>   another creation_date range. Thus no need for deep paging.